# How to retrieve a an array from a multidimensional by the highest value of arrays inside

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to solve out a function to retrieve the highest array set in a condition, the main problem is that verifying an array there are more than 1 true and always need to be the highest value.

My case:

```
        $purchase = 999;
        $rules = array(
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'min' => 200,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 2,
                'min' => 300,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 5,
                'min' => 50,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 3,
                'min' => 2000,
            )
        );
        $getRules = array();
        foreach($rules as $rule){
            if($purchase >= $rule['min']){
                $getRules[] = $rule;
            }
        }
        var_dump($getRules);
```

In this scenario i will get 3 sets of arrays:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["min"]=>
    int(200)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["min"]=>
    int(300)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["min"]=>
    int(50)
  }
}
```

From this 3 sets i need to get the set that has the 'min' key a highest value, i mean i need the array key number 1.

I tried to sort with usort but being in multidimensional it doesn't sort correctly so if somebody passed trough this and has a solution i really appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an additional if statement that checks to see if the rule is larger then a previous rule.

```
    foreach($rules as $rule){
        if($purchase >= $rule['min']){
            $getRules[] = $rule;
            if(!isset($highestRule['min']) || $highestRule['min'] < $rule['min'])){
                $highestRule = $rule;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take your array as a parameter, iterate through it and keep replacing the `$highest_min` and  `$highest_min_index` if the current min is greater than the previous.

At the end, it will have the index of your array where the highest min value resides and will return only that index from your array to give you your array with the highest min.

```
function get_highest_min_array($in_array){

  $out_array = array();
  $highest_min_index = '';
  $highest_min = 0;

  foreach($in_array as $index => $out_array){

    if($out_array['min'] > $highest_min){
      $highest_min_index = $index;
      $highest_min = $out_array['min'];
    }
  }
  return $in_array[$highest_min_index];
}
```